# wagtail comparing revisions produces : render() got an unexpected keyword argument 'context'

Tags: wagtail

On version 1.9, trying out the comparing revisions of a page new feature locally, when :

```
    render() got an unexpected keyword argument 'context'
    Request Method: GET
    Request URL:      http://localhost:8000/admin/pages/48/revisions/compare/488...489/
    Django Version: 1.10.5
    Exception Type: TypeError
    Exception Value:  
    render() got an unexpected keyword argument 'context'
    Exception Location: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-   packages/wagtail/wagtailcore/blocks/base.py in render, line 442
    Python Executable:  /usr/local/bin/python2
    Python Version: 2.7.13
    Python Path:  
    ['/code',
    '/usr/local/bin',
    '/usr/local/lib/python27.zip',
    '/usr/local/lib/python2.7',
    '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2',
    '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
    '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
    '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
    '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages']
    Server time:  Thu, 23 Feb 2017 14:51:34 +0000
    Error during template rendering

    In template /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-    packages/wagtail/wagtailadmin/templates/wagtailadmin/pages/revisions/comp    are.html, error at line 37
    render() got an unexpected keyword argument 'context'
    27              </thead>
    28  
    29              <tbody>
    30                  {% for comp in comparison %}
    31                      <tr>
    32                          <td class="title" valign="top">
    33                              <h2>{{ comp.field_label }}:</h2>
    34                          </td>
    35                          <td class="comparison{% if not  comp.is_field %} no-padding{% endif %}">
    36                              {% if comp.is_field %}
    37                                  {{ comp.htmldiff }}
    38                              {% elif comp.is_child_relation %}
    39                                  {% for child_comp in  comp.get_child_comparisons %}
    40                                      <div class="comparison__child-object {% if child_comp.is_addition %}addition{% elif child_comp.is_deletion %}deletion{% endif %}">
    41                                          {% with child_comp.get_position_change as move %}
    42                                              {% if move %}
    43                                              <div class="help- block help-info">
    44                                                  <p>
    45                                                      {% if move >   0 %}
    46                                                          {%  blocktrans count counter=move %}
    47                                                              Moved   down 1 place.
    Traceback Switch to copy-and-paste view

    /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py in inner
            response = get_response(request) ...
    ▶ Local vars
    /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py   in _legacy_get_response
            response = self._get_response(request) ...
    ▶ Local vars
    /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py in _get_response
                response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e,   request) ...
    ▶ Local vars
    /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py  in _get_response
                response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs) ...
    ▶ Local vars
    /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site- packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py in _cache_controlled
            response = viewfunc(request, *args, **kw) ...
    ▶ Local vars
    /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site- packages/wagtail/wagtailadmin/decorators.py in decorated_view
            return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs) ...
    ▶ Local vars
    /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-  packages/wagtail/wagtailadmin/views/pages.py in revisions_compare
        'comparison': comparison, ...
    ▶ Local vars
    /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/shortcuts.py in render
    content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request,   using=using) ...
    ▶ Local vars
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader.py in  render_to_string
    return template.render(context, request) ...
    ▶ Local vars
    /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site- packages/django/template/backends/django.py in render
            return self.template.render(context) ...
    ▶ Local vars
    /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py in render
                    return self._render(context) ...
    ▶ Local vars
    /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py in    _render
        return self.nodelist.render(context) ...
    ▶ Local vars
    /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py in render
                bit = node.render_annotated(context) ...
    ▶ Local vars
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py in render_annotated
            return self.render(context) ...
    ▶ Local vars
    /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py in render
         return compiled_parent._render(context) ...
    ▶ Local vars
    /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py in _render
        return self.nodelist.render(context) ...
    ▶ Local vars
    /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py in  render
                bit = node.render_annotated(context) ...
    ▶ Local vars
    /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py in render_annotated
            return self.render(context) ...
    ▶ Local vars
    /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py in render
        return compiled_parent._render(context) ...
    ▶ Local vars
    /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py in _render
        return self.nodelist.render(context) ...
    ▶ Local vars
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py in render
                bit = node.render_annotated(context) ...
    ▶ Local vars
    /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py in  render_annotated
            return self.render(context) ...
    ▶ Local vars
    /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py in render
        return compiled_parent._render(context) ...
    ▶ Local vars
    /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py in _render
           return self.nodelist.render(context) ...
    ▶ Local vars
    /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py in render
                bit = node.render_annotated(context) ...
    ▶ Local vars
    /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py in render_annotated
            return self.render(context) ...
    ▶ Local vars
    /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py in render
                 result = block.nodelist.render(context) ...
    ▶ Local vars
    /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py in render
                bit = node.render_annotated(context) ...
    ▶ Local vars
    /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py in   render_annotated
            return self.render(context) ...
    ▶ Local vars
    /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py in render
                result = block.nodelist.render(context) ...
    ▶ Local vars
    /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py in render
                bit = node.render_annotated(context) ...
    ▶ Local vars
    /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py in render_annotated
            return self.render(context) ...
    ▶ Local vars
    /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py in render
                    nodelist.append(node.render_annotated(context)) ...
    ▶ Local vars
    /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py in  render_annotated
            return self.render(context) ...
    ▶ Local vars
    /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py  in render
                return nodelist.render(context) ...
    ▶ Local vars
    /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py in render
                bit = node.render_annotated(context) ...
    ▶ Local vars
    /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py in render_annotated
            return self.render(context) ...
    ▶ Local vars
    /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py in render
            output = self.filter_expression.resolve(context) ...
    ▶ Local vars
    /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py in resolve
                obj = self.var.resolve(context) ...
    ▶ Local vars
    /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py in resolve
            value = self._resolve_lookup(context) ...
    ▶ Local vars
    /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py in _resolve_lookup
                            current = current() ...
    ▶ Local vars
    /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/wagtail/wagtailadmin/compare.py in htmldiff
            BeautifulSoup(force_text(self.val_a), 'html5lib').getText(),   ...
   ▶ Local vars
   /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/encoding.py in    force_text
                s = six.text_type(s) ...
   ▶ Local vars
   /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/wagtail/wagtailcore/blocks/stream_block.py in __str__
        return self.__html__() ...
   ▶ Local vars
   /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/wagtail/wagtailcore/blocks/stream_block.py in __html__
        return self.stream_block.render(self) ...
    ▶ Local vars
    /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site- packages/wagtail/wagtailcore/blocks/base.py in render
            return self.render_basic(value, context=context) ...
    ▶ Local vars
    /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-  packages/wagtail/wagtailcore/blocks/stream_block.py in render_basic
                for child in value ...
    ▶ Local vars
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/wagtail/wagtailcore/blocks/base.py in render
        return self.block.render(self.value, context=context)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you have a custom StreamField block that defines its own `render` method. This method was updated in Wagtail 1.6 to accept a `context` keyword argument, and so you need to update it as described here:

http://docs.wagtail.io/en/stable/releases/1.6.html#render-and-render-basic-methods-on-streamfield-blocks-now-accept-a-context-keyword-argument

The old signature (without the `context` keyword argument) would have continued to work in Wagtail 1.6 and 1.7, but output a deprecation warning; support for it was dropped completely in Wagtail 1.8.

StreamField blocks now allow custom get_template methods for overriding templates in instances from Wagtail 2.0.

http://docs.wagtail.io/en/stable/releases/2.0.html#other-features

Comment: Thanks, that's fixed it. I'd changed them a while back on other sites, but hadn't on this one. Sorry.